# Configure apache2 and host to pass traffic to a docker container with nginx

Tags: apache, docker, nginx

I'm currently running a `ubuntu` webserver with `apache2`, hosting multiple sites and subdomains. I would like to host bitwarden on my own webserver, which is only shipped in a `docker` container with `nginx`.

I would like to use a subdomain e.g. *bitwarden.domain.com* to access bitwarden. But I have no idea how to configure apache2 / host to pass through traffic going to bitwarden.domain.com to the docker container running bitwarden (without affecting the other domains).

My question: How to configure apache2/docker to achieve this? Is there any documentation/tutorial for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting the docker container, grab the container ip, port:
`local_docker_ip`, `local_docker_port`

And you have a couple of options:

Use apache2 Virtual host with a redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  bitwarden.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://{local_docker_ip}:{local_docker_port}/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or use the apache2 [proxy module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). First, enable proxy modules by running the commands:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Then, add the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName bitwarden.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://{local_docker_ip}:{local_docker_port}/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://{local_docker_ip}:{local_docker_port}/
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I was also looking at https://github.com/bitwarden/core/issues/188 to see how to configure the docker container but your answer helped me to setup the proxy. I just changed the listening port to 443, set SSLProxyEngine On and added ssl certificates for security reasons.